# Connecting MixPre-D to a Sony PCM D-50 via a OPT-S/PDIF AES-EBU Converter?

Tags: converter, pcm-d50, spdif

Looking at the new MixPre-D by Sound Devices I got the idea that perhaps it would be possible to connect it to a Sony PCM D-50 digitally. After some googling I found out that there indeed are portable SPDIF-AES/EBU converters such as a HOSA ODL 312. So, my question is: Will I be able to record MixPre-D's AES/EBU XLR output 24-bit signal digitally via the D-50 mini-Toslink input with a converter like this?

Comment: Just to clarify: this setup would be for a shoulder mounted DSLR cinema rig. The converter and the Mixpre-D would be powered with an external battery. Obviously the line level output could be used as well, but if the converter is only less than a hundred dollars perhaps it might be worth it to get one. I've been reading about problems getting the D50 to recognize some SPDIF 24 bit signals, but I'm not sure if it's a common problem or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work. I connected a MixPre-D via XLR AES out to a Hosa ODL-312 then from the 312 to a Sony D-50 via Toslink and the D-50 reports "Unknown Data." I contacted Sound Devices and they replied that MixPre-D AES does not have the SPDIF header data required by the D-50. SD suggested using the XLR out or tape out to the D-50 line in.

Comment: What a pity, was keen on doing that for a small rig. How do you have the MixPre D already? Thought it wasn't out yet. You happy with the machine? 

Comment: I have the MixPre-D now as well. I'm very happy with the machine.. it has all the functions I need at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Asked Sound Devices to consider this as an enhancemnt and they agreed to consider. Made it clear that the request is for the MixPre-D AES output to report the specific header data for the sample rate and bit depth. The hardware is connected correctly and signal is converted by the Hosa ODL-312, but a firmware updgrade is requested to add the specific header data to the AES signal so the Sony D50 will recognize the data stream. They said to watch their web site for a firmware upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on the SD website for the firmware upgrade.